# How to registered Op and Kernel in the binary running in my process?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

server environment : python3.6, tensorflow 1.9, ubuntu mate 16.04, gpu0 : 1080ti, gpu1 : 1080ti

I want to set the tensorflow code to run in c++ and I success save the model graph(graph.pb) and check point(model.max.ckpt).

Next, copy freeze graph file (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) to tensorflow model directory

and I typed command but, I only meet fail message.

here is original tensorflow model link (https://github.com/kentonl/e2e-coref)

**command**

```
python3 freeze_graph.py --input_graph graph.pb --input_checkpointmodel.max.ckpt --output_graph frozen_graph.pb --output_node_names softmax
```

**coref_kernels.so**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

coref_op_library = tf.load_op_library("./coref_kernels.so")

extract_spans = coref_op_library.extract_spans
tf.NotDifferentiable("ExtractSpans")
```

**whole error message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "freeze_graph.py", line 382, in <module>
  run_main()
File "freeze_graph.py", line 379, in run_main
  app.run(main=my_main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
File "freeze_graph.py", line 378, in <lambda>
  my_main = lambda unused_args: main(unused_args, flags)
File "freeze_graph.py", line 272, in main
  flags.saved_model_tags, checkpoint_version)
File "freeze_graph.py", line 254, in freeze_graph
  checkpoint_version=checkpoint_version)
File "freeze_graph.py", line 99, in freeze_graph_with_def_protos
_ = importer.import_graph_def(input_graph_def, name="")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 432, in new_func
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 418, in import_graph_def
  graph._c_graph, serialized, options)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Op type not registered 'ExtractSpans' in binary running on Z370-Pro4. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this by adding the following before my own codes:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

coref_op_library = tf.load_op_library("./coref_kernels.so")

extract_spans = coref_op_library.extract_spans
tf.NotDifferentiable("ExtractSpans")
```